# Whatsapp Cloud API message international format and error with Webhook

Tags: javascript, whatsapp, whatsapi, glitch.com

I am using the whatsapp api with webhooks, however I can't receive my message when I write in the chat.

This is my code, in my number I get my country code (MX) and my phone number from whatsapp:
e.g. 521xxxxxxxxxx, but add a '1' after my country code and before my phone number and I don't get the message:

```js
app.post("/webhook", (req, res) => {
  let body = req.body;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));

  if (req.body.object) {
    if (
      req.body.entry &&
      req.body.entry[0].changes &&
      req.body.entry[0].changes[0] &&
      req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages &&
      req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0]
    ) {
      let phone_number_id =
        req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.metadata.phone_number_id;
      let from = req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].from;
      let msg_body = req.body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].text.body;the message text from the webhook payload
      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url:
          "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/" +
          phone_number_id +
          "/messages?access_token=" +
          token,
        data: {
          messaging_product: "whatsapp",
          to: from,//------------------>521(phone_number)
          text: { body: "Ack: " + msg_body },
        },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      }).catch((error)=>{console.log(error)});
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
});
```

I receive this:

```
[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400] {
  message: 'Request failed with status code 400',
  name: 'AxiosError',
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2',
      'Content-Length': 79
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/number/messages?access_token=Mytoken',
    data: '{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","to":"521xxxxxxxxxx","text":{"body":"Ack: ' +
      'dc"}}'
  },
  request: ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      socket: [Function],
      abort: [Function],
      aborted: [Function],
      connect: [Function],
      error: [Function],
      timeout: [Function],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: false,
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'graph.facebook.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 95,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    connection: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: false,
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'graph.facebook.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: false,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 95,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'POST ' +
      '/v12.0/number/messages?access_token=Mytoken' +
      'HTTP/1.1\r' +
      '\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r' +
      '\nContent-Type: application/json\r' +
      '\nUser-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r' +
      '\nContent-Length: 79\r' +
      '\nHost: graph.facebook.com\r' +
      '\nConnection: close\r' +
      '\n\r' +
      '\n',
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object]
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/v12.0/number/messages?access_token=Mytoken',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: false,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular],
      responseUrl: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/number/messages?access_token=Mytoken',
      redirects: []
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 79,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function],
      _currentRequest: [Circular],
      _currentUrl: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/number/messages?access_token=Mytoken'
    },
    [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
    [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: {
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      vary: 'Origin, Accept-Encoding',
      'x-business-use-case-usage': '{"WhatsApp_Business_id":[{"type":"whatsapp","call_count":1,"total_cputime":1,"total_time":1,"estimated_time_to_regain_access":0}]}',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'www-authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" ' +
        '"(#131030) Recipient phone number not in allowed ' +
        'list"',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'facebook-api-version': 'v19.0',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15552000; preload',
      pragma: 'no-cache',
      'cache-control': 'no-store',
      expires: 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT',
      'x-fb-request-id': 'A4rSbxyIJNyOf4R5r1pPkmk',
      'x-fb-trace-id': 'ATu77bL3PMb',
      'x-fb-rev': '1011688366',
      'x-stack': 'www',
      'x-fb-debug': 'J+fSMhXGpY7EOvDPb+Bf0lGTUe/OgXwlySpC14MS0JNJL+eXFrmiELIAMBhVh8j36y0Q2vFDiXGZit2yNtrMoQ==',
      date: 'Tue, 27 Feb 2024 21:00:29 GMT',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      'proxy-status': 'http_request_error; ' +
        'e_clientaddr="AcL58ZR0DI9KDOj5eMoVAZg-f5FwcwjY6s07lJ0LpyF4_wc6VZA1RkQaE2RfjTo_WT3AynbeCXCQI1j3gYHS3e_dZXuXC9HN5aaRumYFpu4EFy_1eQ"; ' +
        'e_fb_vipport="AcK5ONstOkchBHFvIlZoDqmZfFKMwucd1XsGYo8bm86fqFA-o9UeBqQS3biH"; ' +
        'e_upip="AcIGZA5ozrram3zvwHpdysfH2v-83JoYqAyPfTIrEC8vUCSqBckYNKEY8mx4mhKbMNAoCLhAXA52flp5NkhVTU188knAxP61wsg"; ' +
        'e_fb_hostheader="AcLdwktEbpovXClbGu6IFN0K9tlmVCmCtKQ7DFFdGsOECLu_Bn7eY2_ukkczwJUkp2oQ8pB4k5y66lZV"; ' +
        'e_fb_vipaddr="AcKN9Yn1EoXzBbv6WeC37NhCpQd8LBv2CE1yY8gyAMTiCjHihFd60TY5seJG3pK542-KSrO-xfK823JV1yWnwjIbtu0xTjO_rA"; ' +
        'e_fb_requesthandler="AcI8WdQuUQBeJBsPjGIGnRjC0F61uqubD8JXORvjWtJyz0GftPNW7bbv_JJ8QYVFGetMscD6NBA"; ' +
        'e_fb_builduser="AcKTd7iW4Ev_O8dt-w7A2Yi_rOhXnfNlqQwQQq03c4vVeiHmyBRcgta5jjjeSA58100"; ' +
        'e_fb_binaryversion="AcLZ-iEQXpObJYssQTQdmbQh6JQLuIfsTweRqFa0K6OKpQ8q1yRVhLUFGuzw1n_8Zht9-g9MKYjuvVbw72t8xWA8OVqVUXEdDyM"; ' +
        'e_proxy="AcLC3wcuh2BtM47AQXQvv8I9GzJvYlMx4160zHih8VdVVTZb4W5NFv2d0_LRjCW57Xc0uERkMb-GH7oT0HU", ' +
        'http_request_error; ' +
        'e_clientaddr="AcItFG-AcAHvymkWscj4syktDm371pYva2x46yxQCeDLI7PbHPDkzlcRDi6gYiGvGEWQ7_sSO6DCwLrIhQ"; ' +
        'e_fb_vipport="AcJOtyZ7_bnfdk8N8-GKlFS6Iz13HEg9SmmHklUsg-4der1GLqYSQeII231g"; ' +
        'e_upip="AcIJorrXD3SMBDdgp9-4SQyjrXVdPViOkc4YCbox4HsSIA-sqoybCEYsWkpxrJ4_2jSYpM1G1iE6GccdKXOJhoTzr81stbCIZQ"; ' +
        'e_fb_hostheader="AcJXaW1xFHUWGb6s0v-AtUULyf_mOykVZ4iLwvdpzSYQBnQ_cKRYDI-eDNHR6HROSMQT4lQFldDZgT5w"; ' +
        'e_fb_vipaddr="AcKz4dDMkcUhGTLcrGeyMHW2crcZvhpqwNu-hol3mpZSzMV0VUEqeqn7IdeNTL_YnyXqEA"; ' +
        'e_fb_requesthandler="AcJ9zSgz_zrHT0tOmByndPZTqKYBQRPj6ziyFhPF-CU_RN_QlFbZTp4b6SJkjlv-A6Sskl6bau8"; ' +
        'e_fb_builduser="AcLKeTVsLgi60eX1B5MtHQdQRIDUQiBh91JFX7L7xEDYqftu9eRKV0EGXz2IiJvLacs"; ' +
        'e_fb_binaryversion="AcK4g_jOdwqfncbaMwKkRm-_0ueZv_eOvAB83pIto9MAVlE75bsfQEvXBfVYx8sOmmxZWqnAnSTbI8unHAa3wPdNdkI83KH6qTc"; ' +
        'e_proxy="AcKxFOXFPi_6v5boo7PO0LnhyLqh2AAuiuhIX2Bef4cXmFuSzC_7X5Q3ZZwRmprXo6y3YYL9fVSdmB-Y"',
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400',
      connection: 'close'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object],
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/number/messages?access_token=Mytoken',
      data: '{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","to":"521xxxxxxxxxx","text":{"body":"Ack: ' +
        'dc"}}'
    },
    request: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST ' +
        '/v12.0/number/messages?access_token=Mytoken' +
        'HTTP/1.1\r' +
        '\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r' +
        '\nContent-Type: application/json\r' +
        '\nUser-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r' +
        '\nContent-Length: 79\r' +
        '\nHost: graph.facebook.com\r' +
        '\nConnection: close\r' +
        '\n\r' +
        '\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/v12.0/number/messages?access_token=Mytoken',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
      [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object]
    },
    data: { error: [Object] }
  }
}
```

If I remove the '1' in the 'from' variable I receve it, but whatsapp send it several times with different messages that I don't send every now and then. Is there a way to use the international format?, or a function that I can use to become it?. I think that each country has different formats so, use a function that remove the '1' in 3rd position isn't correct and I don't know if that is caused by the format and the several sends.

What Can I do?. Thanks.

[image]